# Does WinHttpHandler Implement HTTP/2 Multiplexing Automatically?

Tags: c#, http2

If I am making an immense amount of simultaneous requests to the same host over HTTP/2 using `WinHttpHandler` as the handler of the `HttpClient`, is multiplexing carried out automatically? For example if I set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100`, then there will be at most 100 concurrent TCP socket connections at a given time. If I am sending 1000 requests using async tasks, will the 101st request wait until one of the prior request's response is received and that connection becomes available, or will the connection be available and the 101st request be sent without waiting the response?

Comment: First, you need to set the context (.NET Framework? .NET Core?) If .NET Core, related discussions can be found at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx

Comment: @LexLi .NET Framework